# Build a repository with apt-mirror for ubuntu with changelogs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, apt-mirror

is it possible to create an internal mirror of the ubuntu update repository with apt-mirror including **all the changelogs**.

I have the following output when i ask for the changelog of a package:

```
apt-get changelog iptraf
```

> Holen: 1 Änderungsprotokoll (Changelog) für iptraf
>   (http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/i/iptraf/iptraf_3.0.0-8.1/changelog)
>   [15,5 kB] Es wurden 15,5 kB in 0 s geholt (78,1 kB/s).

When I go to http://changelogs.ubuntu.com there is all the data I need.

Is there a possibility to sync these changelogs with apt-mirror ? I want to have it inside our closed network.

Thank you for the help!

Fake4d